# DropLink datasource item reference with custom dataprovider in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, dataprovider

**How do bind a DropLink using a custom dataprovider?**

More info:
I am trying to build a product catalogue site using Sitecore. Each product in the sitecore content tree can have a star rating and short text review attached to it (*which will be linked to a user extended with a profile provider but that is another question*).

I am planning to store the review information in an external database and reference it using a custom dataprovider. I have downloaded the NorthwindDataProvider from the Shared Source ([here](http://trac.sitecore.net/NorthwindDataProvider/)) and have altered it to use a table which contains the rating, text and a uniqueidentifier field to store the ID of the product from in sitecore the review is attached to.

The template field is a droplink and the datasource is set to the products in the catalogue.

When I edit a review in the custom dataprovider using the sitecore content editor, the droplink states 'Value not in selection list' even if I select one of the populated products and save using sitecore.

It is saving the ID in the database but if I look at the raw value it displays the id without the curly brackets. Working droplink fields' raw values appear to contain the brackets.

To create a review, I am using a jquery post to a webservice which writes to the database using an external datacontext. Should I be using some Sitecore API to use the custom dataprovider instead?

Any information using custom dataproviders would be helpful. The documentation I've been able to find has all stated what can be done but I'm struggling to find actual implementation.

Comment: Heres some links that helped me: http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2011/January/Black-Art-of-Sitecore-Data-Providers, For an implementation check out http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Shared%20Source/Shared%20Source%205,-d-,3/Data%20Providers/SQL%20Data%20Provider/Downloads.aspx

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing is that you have a template field and you're using droplink which is going to store the guid for the item selected. I'm not quite clear on whether or not you're pointing the datasource to a Sitecore item or not.. but that's essential if you're using droplink.  Here's what I would suggest instead for the most straight forward way to do this:

Create a template that you add fields to handle the logic dealing with your catalog items.  How you do that is your choice and Sitecore doesn't care since its only going to deal with the item and all it cares about is finding an item... you write business logic to manipulate the external data.

Once you have a folder that stores your catalog items, you could easily write a script to be triggered by the Rules engine in Sitecore or a Sitecore task that runs regularly to get your catalog items to add/update or remove the corresponding list of Sitecore items.

Also, another option that is more complex to implement, but if you have multiple data sources on your site, is a valid approach, is to use an object framework (like the Entity framework) as a data object layer that allows you to create and populate common objects with from any data source.

Hope this is helpful!